# Why are there so many ways to hook up a view to an event in UIKit?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa, uikit

Okay, the question is somewhat rhetorical. :-) I know the answer is "because they designed it that way" but still...

I'm learning iOS development and find myself stumbling over all the various ways to make a widget (aka View/UIView) respond to an event. So far I've found:

- IBAction
- IBOutlet
- Delegates
- addTarget:action:forControlEvents:
- Gesture Recognizers
- Notifications

(...not to mention that Interface Builder supports some of these techniques, but not all, and even the ones it does support don't always work, or require some custom coding before magically appearing.)

1. Are there any others I've missed?
2. Is there any rational, *a priori* way to tell what technique to use with a particular widget?
3. Is there any centralized list of which widgets support which cases? Or will I have to learn through a combination of docs, sample code and guesswork?

Comment: "not constructive?" Really? Did those who closed this actually read the full question? How are my 3 points not "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"?

Answer (score 2):

Every thing in that list has a different purpose and just understanding iOS development along with research will make you familiar with them. For instance an IBAction is connecting to an event through Interface builder while an IBOutlet is connecting to the UI Element in Interface Builder. A complete answer to your question is really a long tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd hope for something less than a tutorial and more like a cheat sheet. For example, in researching my own question, I just discovered `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` is defined on `UIControl`, which means it's for buttons and sliders but not tables or toolbars. It'd be nice to have an annotated version of the [UIKit Class Hierarchy](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Art/uikit_classes.jpg) which shows the myriad event hookups.

Comment: Yeah I understand but from my experience you are listing a bunch of things that each require some explanation and are really a piece of a big topic in themselves. For example a delegate doesn't have to have anything to do with UI or a view and is a core design pattern in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer. I'll take a stab at listing some rules as I discover them. (Maybe I'll make it a community wiki.)

- The [Communicating With Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html) guide covers outlets, delegates, data sources, IBActions (aka "the target-action mechanism"), and notifications (`NSNotificationCenter` *et al.*)
- Apparently each control decides what user event is hooked up when you control-drag an `IBAction` onto it (usually Touch Up Inside), but if you open the Connections Inspector, you can choose from a long list of events and hook any of them onto your `IBAction` methods.
- `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` is defined on `UIControl`, which means it's for buttons and sliders but not tables or toolbars.